# Shortest way to linearize a list in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, list, dictionary

I want to make a list with linearly increasing values from a list with non-linearly increasing values in Python. For example

```
input =[10,10,10,6,6,4,1,1,1,10,10]
```

should be transformed to:

```
output=[0,0,0,1,1,2,3,3,3,0,0]
```

My code uses a python dictionary

```
def linearize(input):
    """
    Remap a input list containing values in non linear-indices list
    i.e.
    input = [10,10,10,6,6,3,1,1]
    output= [0,0,0,1,1,2,3,3] 
    """
    remap={}
    i=0
    output=[0]*len(input)
    for x in input:
        if x not in remap.keys():
            remap[x]=i
            i=i+1
    for i in range(0,len(input)):
        output[i]=remap[input[i]]
    return output
```

but I know this code can be more efficient. Some ideas to do this task better and in a more pythonic way, Numpy is an option?
This function has to be called very frequently on big lists.

Comment: Change `if x not in remap.keys():` to `if x not in remap:`. That should give you a considerable performance gain.

Comment: Your list of non-linearly increasing values isn't increasing.  Are you just speaking of _changes_ in the value?

Comment: What output you expect when `input = [8,8,6,6,3,8]`?
`[0,0,1,1,2,3]` or `[0,0,1,1,2,0]`?

Comment: @YuriyKovalev: i'd expect [0,0,1,1,2,0]

Comment: @linello Can you add that example to the question to make it clear for everybody?

Comment: Done, added this to the example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [your comment in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22037771/shortest-way-to-linearize-a-list-in-python/22038626#comment33411613_22037771), you are looking for something like this

```
data = [8,8,6,6,3,8]
from itertools import count
from collections import defaultdict
counter = defaultdict(lambda x=count(): next(x))
print([counter[item] for item in data])
# [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0]
```

[Thanks to poke](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/14959717#14959717),

```
list(map(lambda i, c=defaultdict(lambda c=count(): next(c)): c[i], data))
```

Its just a one liner now :)

Comment: Now _this_ beats it.  Very clever usage of `count().next` indeed.

Comment: This is brilliant, very clever. Python 3 needs `defaultdict(count().__next__)` btw.

Comment: It's a pity that `[defaultdict(count().next)[item] for item in a]` isn't working, though.

Comment: Well, you could do this: `list(map(lambda i, c=defaultdict(lambda c=count(): next(c)): c[i], data))`

Answer (score 2):

Use `collections.OrderedDict`:

```
In [802]: from collections import OrderedDict
     ...: odk=OrderedDict.fromkeys(l).keys()
     ...: odk={k:i for i, k in enumerate(odk)}
     ...: [odk[i] for i in l]
Out[802]: [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: `This function has to be called very frequently on big lists.` You are creating a new object every time and getting the `index` for every element. This will make the situation worse.

Comment: You're still calling `index` for every item of `l`. `index` runs in linear time, so this algorithm is going to suffer quadratic performance.

Comment: @user2357112 I made `odk` a dict, it should be linear in time now.

Comment: @zhangxaochen: .. almost an hour and forty five minutes after you post your original code, I posted the fixed linear version, and then within a minute or two you update yours the same way?  Coincidences can happen, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution without imports:

```
input =[10,10,10,6,6,4,1,1,1,10,10]
d = {}
result = [d.setdefault(x, len(d)) for x in input]
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this function using numpy which in my tests worked faster than yours when input list was very big like 2,000,000 elements.

```
import numpy as np
def linearize(input):
    unique, inverse = np.unique(input, return_inverse=True)
    output = (len(unique)-1) - inverse
    return output
```

Also, this function **only works if your input is in Descending order** like your example.
Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I've modified my example, the input list hasn't necessarily to be ordered.

Comment: I modified my answer to emphasize that input should be ordered for my case. Thanks.